# SWT Transparent Button/Label

Tags: java, swt

I have researched this for days.  It appears that most folks want to place buttons on a transparent canvas or shell.  I need to place transparent clickable objects over a canvas/component.  In my testing I find that if I don't attempt to put the object on the canvas it simply never displays.

In the final project the application will be showing animated objects with a number of controls that I plan to use images for.

In the example I am trying to work out I have taken Snipped195 which displays a turning torus.  I am attempting to place an image label over the torus such that as the torus turns it will show through the area of the label that is transparent.  I have set up a gif file that is a red plus sign and has a transparent background.  I also picked up some code (can't remember where it came from now) that is part of the paintControl method that looks for transparent pixels and builds a Region object.  The region object obviously is doing what it needs to do to define where the image goes.  Do I need to apply the region somehow to the image instead of the canvas?

At first when I tried to do this I did get the image displayed.  However where the transparent areas where it displayed white.  After implementing the paintControl code it at least handled the transparent area properly.  Now I need to get the actual image content to display.

I built an object to take care of the image label.  I called it TransparentImageLabel.  It looks like:

```
public class TransparentImageLabel extends Canvas {

    private Image labelImage;

    public TransparentImageLabel(Composite parent, Image image, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        this.labelImage = image;
        addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
            public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
                TransparentImageLabel.this.widgetDisposed(e);
            }
        });
        addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                TransparentImageLabel.this.paintControl(e);
            }
        });
    }

    private void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {

    }

    private void paintControl(PaintEvent event) {
        System.out.println("at paint control");
        ImageData imgData = this.labelImage.getImageData();
        Region region = new Region();
        if (imgData.alphaData != null) {
            Rectangle pixel = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1);
            for (int y = 0; y < imgData.height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < imgData.width; x++) {
                    if (imgData.getAlpha(x, y) == 255) {
                        pixel.x = imgData.x + x;
                        pixel.y = imgData.y + y;
                        region.add(pixel);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            ImageData mask = imgData.getTransparencyMask();
            Rectangle pixel = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1);
            for (int y = 0; y < mask.height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < mask.width; x++) {
                    if (mask.getPixel(x, y) != 0) {
                        pixel.x = imgData.x + x;
                        pixel.y = imgData.y + y;
                        region.add(pixel);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        this.setRegion(region);
        event.gc.drawImage(labelImage, this.getBounds().x, this.getBounds().y);
        region.dispose();
    }
}
```

After adding this to Snipped195 the code looks like:

```
public class Snippet195 {

    private Image redPlus;

    static void drawTorus(float r, float R, int nsides, int rings) {
        float ringDelta = 2.0f * (float) Math.PI / rings;
        float sideDelta = 2.0f * (float) Math.PI / nsides;
        float theta = 0.0f, cosTheta = 1.0f, sinTheta = 0.0f;
        for (int i = rings - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            float theta1 = theta + ringDelta;
            float cosTheta1 = (float) Math.cos(theta1);
            float sinTheta1 = (float) Math.sin(theta1);
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUAD_STRIP);
            float phi = 0.0f;
            for (int j = nsides; j >= 0; j--) {
                phi += sideDelta;
                float cosPhi = (float) Math.cos(phi);
                float sinPhi = (float) Math.sin(phi);
                float dist = R + r * cosPhi;
                GL11.glNormal3f(cosTheta1 * cosPhi, -sinTheta1 * cosPhi, sinPhi);
                GL11.glVertex3f(cosTheta1 * dist, -sinTheta1 * dist, r * sinPhi);
                GL11.glNormal3f(cosTheta * cosPhi, -sinTheta * cosPhi, sinPhi);
                GL11.glVertex3f(cosTheta * dist, -sinTheta * dist, r * sinPhi);
            }
            GL11.glEnd();
            theta = theta1;
            cosTheta = cosTheta1;
            sinTheta = sinTheta1;
        }
    }

    private Snippet195() {
        final Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        comp.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        GLData data = new GLData();
        data.doubleBuffer = true;
        redPlus = new Image(shell.getDisplay(), new ImageData(
                Snippet237.class.getResourceAsStream("/red-plus.png")));
        final GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(comp, SWT.NONE, data);

        canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                e.gc.setAlpha(15);
                e.gc.drawImage(Snippet195.this.redPlus, 0, 0);
            }
        });

        canvas.setCurrent();
        try {
            GLContext.useContext(canvas);
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        canvas.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                Rectangle bounds = canvas.getBounds();
                float fAspect = (float) bounds.width / (float) bounds.height;
                canvas.setCurrent();
                try {
                    GLContext.useContext(canvas);
                } catch (LWJGLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                GL11.glViewport(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height);
                GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
                GL11.glLoadIdentity();
                GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, fAspect, 0.5f, 400.0f);
                GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
                GL11.glLoadIdentity();
            }
        });

        GL11.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);
        GL11.glClearDepth(1.0);
        GL11.glLineWidth(2);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        TransparentImageLabel redPlusLabel = new TransparentImageLabel(canvas,
                redPlus, SWT.NONE);
        redPlusLabel.setSize(48, 48);
        redPlusLabel.setLocation(500, 200);
        shell.setText("SWT/LWJGL Example");
        shell.setSize(880, 720);
        shell.open();
        final Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            int rot = 0;

            public void run() {
                if (!canvas.isDisposed()) {
                    canvas.setCurrent();
                    try {
                        GLContext.useContext(canvas);
                    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT
                            | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                    GL11.glClearColor(.3f, .5f, .8f, 1.0f);
                    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
                    GL11.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
                    float frot = rot;
                    GL11.glRotatef(0.15f * rot, 2.0f * frot, 10.0f * frot, 1.0f);
                    GL11.glRotatef(0.3f * rot, 3.0f * frot, 1.0f * frot, 1.0f);
                    rot++;
                    GL11.glPolygonMode(GL11.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL11.GL_LINE);
                    GL11.glColor3f(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f);
                    drawTorus(1, 1.9f + ((float) Math.sin((0.004f * frot))), 25, 75);
                    canvas.swapBuffers();
                    display.asyncExec(this);
                }
            }
        };
        canvas.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                run.run();
            }
        });
        display.asyncExec(run);

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Snippet195();
    }
}
```

I have to be close.  The areas of the image that are defined as transparent are being drawn as transparent.  But I'm not getting anything but a white plus instead of the red that is in the image.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the transparent image you're trying to draw to canvas..?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `TransparentImageLabel#paintControl(..)` method. Correct the second last line to the following:

```java
event.gc.drawImage(labelImage, 0, 0);
```

Since you are drawing within the context of the canvas so the coordinates you specify for location should be relative to that `Canvas`. You are currently using the location of `canvas` which is returned relative to it's parent.

Comment: That fixed the problem.  It works fine over the rotating helix.  thank you very much.  Since it was picked up from suggestions on forums I'm still learning how the code works.  I tested this with the rotating helix.  But it will be used to go over a moving map.  The map is redrawn 25 times a sec with the center being re-positioned using OpenGL. The transparent button needs a redraw event tied to the map so it can redraw every time the map is drawn.  The purpose of the canvas.addPaintListener is to signal a redraw of the button every time the helix is redrawn.   Is that correct?

Comment: Its been a while I read this code, so I am not exactly sure. But you can try it out. Since the image you are adding is a separate control (a child of the GLCanvas) so it is possible that it does not need redrawing every time the parent is drawn. Try it out and let me know too. And you might wanna accept the answer if it solved the problem.